# What would be a good book or video for a 15 year old average high school student to teach himself the basics of discrete math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request

I am currently 15 in the ninth grade, trying to prepare for the ioi (internetional Olympiad in informatics) and I need to learn some basics of discrete math. I am an ok high school math student and was wondering if u have any resources from where I can learn basics of discrete math.

Comment: Stanley's [Enumerative Combinatorics](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/) is a classic.  It is [accessible to various age ranges](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/photos/fans.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the following recommendations for you.

1. The book titled "The Art and Craft of Problem Solving" by Paul Zeitz. I am a 35 year old man who has been following this book for more than two years now. I can attest to the fact that I could not solve a single IMO (international mathematical olympiad) problem before I studied this book but now, I am consistently solving problems that appeared in IMO. (FYI IMO is supposed to be the toughest contest in mathematics today).
2. The video lectures by the same author, namely Paul Zeitz. The title is also the same namely "The Art and Craft of Problem Solving" and it is a part of the series in the "Great Courses."

I suggest you go through the videos first (i.e #2 above) and then read the book (#1 above). I did it in the opposite order but I realized that when I heard the author speak, the subject matter sunk in more effectively than when I read the book. It takes many readings to understand the book but the same content somehow seems more easily understood when you listen to the lectures.

The following is copied from another website about the author.

"About the Author Paul Zeitz studied history at Harvard and received a Ph.D. in mathematics from the University of California, Berkeley. He taught high school math in San Francisco and Colorado and currently is an associate professor at the University of San Francisco. He won the USA Mathematical Olympiad (USAMO) and was a member of the first American team to participate in the International Mathematical Olympiad (IMO) in 1974. Since 1985, he has composed and edited problems for several national math contests, including the USAMO. He has helped train several American IMO teams, most notably the 1994 "Dream Team" which, for the first time in history, achieved a perfect score."

Finally, I want to mention that for beginners like you and me, ***the most important thing is to master the material from one book***. I cannot stress that fact enough. The skills needed are very very hard to learn so it will be a steep curve. The last thing you must be doing is to get distracted by other books/sources. Stick to one book, the book that you think is best suited for you, and master it first. When you are done, then it will make sense to read material from other sources, possibly containing harder problems.

Take it from a person who is also very average in math (namely myself). Paul Zeitz is right when he says the following.

• **Problem solving can be taught and can be learned.**

• Success at solving problems is crucially dependent on psychological factors.
Attributes like confidence, concentration, and courage are vitally important.

• No-holds-barred investigation is at least as important as rigorous argument.

• The non-psychological aspects of problem solving are a mix of strategic principles, more focused tactical approaches, and narrowly defined technical tools.

• Knowledge of folklore (for example, the pigeonhole principle or Conway 's
Checker problem) is as important as mastery of technical tools.

Good luck!